# Не получаю ссылку на объект из родительского класса

Tags: java

Всем, добрый день.

Такая проблема, у меня имеется вот такая структура

```
public abstract class MainController implements Initializable {

  protected Connector connector;

  @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        connector = new Connector();
    
    }
}


public class TabPaneController<T> extends MainController {

    protected ObservableList<T> observableList;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        super.initialize(location,resources);
        observableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    }
}

public class FirstTabController extends TabPaneController<Instrument> {
   @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        //super.initialize(location, resources);  // Если я раскомментирую эту строку то все норм
        System.out.print(connector == null);
    }
}
```

Проблема собственно заключается в том, что в `FirstTabController` я не вижу проинициилизированный объект `Connector`. Но, если я расскоментирую строку  `super.initialize(location, resources);`  то у меня `connector` создастся дважды. Не могу понять почему.

Также вопрос, правильно ли я понимаю, что в моей структуре

MainController -> TabPaneController -> FirstTabController, сначала создается FirstTabController,а MainController  в последнюю очередь?

Такой вывод я сделал на основании прохода дебагером по точкам остановы.

Comment: вы должны видеть `Connector`. Он имеет доступ `protected` - т.е. во всех классах наследниках он будет виден и доступен

Comment: я не очень силен в FX(десктоп - не самое распространенное в Java), но initialize -не обычный метод (он предоставлен вам свыше самим FX). посему эти методы будет запускать сам FX. прще всего, на мой взгляд, создать свой метод в классе MainController, например init, оставляя initialize  не переопределенным, обращаться к нему через super.init(). с высокой вероятностью вам контроллер в этом случае будет создан 1 раз

Answer (score 0):

Сначала вызывается конструкторы по цепочке:

```
MainController -> TabPaneController -> FirstTabController
```

Далее инициализируются поля обозначенные `@FXML` потом вызывается `initialize()`

То есть в ходе вызова конструктора создастся поле `Connector` - со значением `null`, далее в ходе `initialize()` (если раскомментировать строчку `super.initialize()`) будет заново инициализировано поле `Connector`

Я бы предложил зафигачить конструктор в `MainController` типа:

```
public abstract class MainController implements Initializable {

  protected Connector connector;
  
  protected MainController() {
      this.connector = new Connector();
  }    

  @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    }
}
```

Что позволит инициализировать `Connector` только 1 раз.

Comment: Судя по логам, которые у меня пишутся, данные способ вызывает ` protected MainController() {
      this.connector = new Connector();
  }` 4 раза. При иницилизации самого `MainController`, а также при вызове наследника каждый раз